# Transform table to json object SQL like dictionary?

Tags: c#, sql, json, sql-server

I have a table with two column, I am trying to convert a query to an object with key value pairs to save it to a dictionary in c #.

**C# code convert Json Object to dictionary**

```
string JsonDictionary;
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(JsonDictionary);
```

**My table in sql server:**

[image]

**My query:**

```
SELECT 
    C.[Key]
    ,C.[Value]
FROM dbo.Settings C
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

**Output query:**

```
{
    "Key": "userName",
    "Value": "userNameValue"
},
{
    "Key": "password",
    "Value": "passwordValue"
},
{
    "Key": "domain",
    "Value": "domainValue"
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "userName": "userNameValue",
    "password": "passwordValue",
    "domain": "domainValue"
}
```

I've searched but can't find a solution

Comment: So, you're trying to do this in SQL? Or are you open to just selecting the values from the table and then doing a simple conversion in C#?

Comment: I am trying to get it from SQL query but I am open to getting it from c # code.

Comment: Use entity framework for any db stuff. Way better than doing things manually

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it if you are using EntityFramework:

```
var dict = _context.Settings.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

If you are using Dapper, then it would look something like this:

```
var dict = conn.Query<KeyValuePair<string, string>>("SELECT Key, Value FROM Settings")
  .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Sample using the Northwind Database here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/22sZ7H

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't deal well with dynamic keys. You would need to do this with dynamic SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @paths nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
      QUOTENAME(c.[Key]) + N' = MAX(CASE WHEN c.[Key] = ' + QUOTENAME(c.[Key], '''') + ' THEN c.Value END)', ',
    ')

    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Key] FROM dbo.Settings) C
);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT 
    ' + @cols + '
FROM dbo.Settings C
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
';

PRINT @sql; --for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pivot your thinking?

```sql
create table dbo.Settings (
  [Key] nvarchar(20),
  [Value] nvarchar(20)
);

insert dbo.Settings ([Key], [Value]) values
  ('userName', 'userNameValue'),
  ('password', 'passwordValue'),
  ('domain', 'domainValue');

select [userName], [password], [domain]
from dbo.Settings src
pivot (max([Value]) for [Key] in ([userName], [password], [domain])) pvt
for json path, without_array_wrapper;
```

This yields the JSON result:

```json
{
    "userName": "userNameValue",
    "password": "passwordValue",
    "domain": "domainValue"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Post Owner is open for the C# solution.

When the data is from `List<T>`, you can use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-5.0) to convert to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

> From List

```cs
using System.Linq;

// Result from DB
List<KeyValue> data = new List<KeyValue>
{
    new KeyValue
    {
        Key = "userName", Value = "userNameValue"
    },
    new KeyValue
    {
        Key = "password", Value = "passwordValue"
    },
    new KeyValue
    {
        Key = "domain", Value = "domainValue"
    }
};
        
Dictionary<string, string> dict = data.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
}
```

```cs
public class KeyValue
{
    public string Key {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

[Sample program (From `List<T>`)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7TOo0h)

---

When data is from `DataTable`, you iterate with `dt.Rows` and add into `Dictionary<string, string>`.

> From `DataTable`

```cs
using System.Data;

#region Mock DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
        
var rowOne = dt.NewRow();
rowOne["Key"] = "userName";
rowOne["Value"] = "userNameValue";
        
var rowTwo = dt.NewRow();
rowTwo["Key"] = "password";
rowTwo["Value"] = "passwordValue";
        
var rowThree = dt.NewRow();
rowThree["Key"] = "domain";
rowThree["Value"] = "domainValue";
        
dt.Rows.Add(rowOne);
dt.Rows.Add(rowTwo);
dt.Rows.Add(rowThree);
#endregion
        
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    dict.Add(row["Key"].ToString(), row["Value"].ToString());
}
                
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}, Value: {kvp.Value}");
}
```

[Sample program (From `DataTable`)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ioshL)

Answer (score -1):

**Use concatenation to construct a simple json object**

```
DECLARE
    @Settings VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT 
    @Settings = COALESCE(@Settings + ', ', '') + '"' + C.[Key] + '":"' +  C.[Value] + '"'
FROM dbo.Settings C

SELECT CONCAT('{', @Settings, '}')
```